# DLL references in the deployment server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

In the Production/Deployment server, where do i look if the DLL references are placed at the right places for a website? I tried checking in the Bin folder and i have them. Is there anywhere else i need to check, because when i build and compile, my application seems to be working fine by using DLL's and connecting to the database but when i open the live website, NO. This is a Visual Studio 2005 project deployed using Visual Studio 2008 in Windows Server 2008.

Comment: You need to slow down. Exactly what error are you getting? What makes you think there is a problem with the location of the DLLs?

Comment: Bin is correct I think -- could be that you just need to convert the folder to an application?

Comment: Agreed with John. Do you have RDP access to the server? Can you change your config to show you a specific error message?
            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
Then open the page in a browser (while remoted to the server) and see what error(s) you get.

[Web Config <customErrors mode="Off"/>](http://forums.asp.net/t/1267844.aspx/1)

Comment: @JohnSaunders The application does not use Business Layer that i have as a DLL to connect to the databases. I hope i am clear.

Comment: Still not clear what your problem is. If the correct DLLs are in the bin folder, then everything should be fine, if they're the correct DLLs. Why do you think you have a problem with the DLLs?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, Sorry, i am confused and honestly i dont know why i think its DLL!! When i built and compiled in the server, i connect to the database and not when i go live, so i thought its because of DLL. I am ignorant in this stuff. You think its not DLL?

Comment: I think you need to learn how to find out what's wrong with your web site. This won't be the last problem you have with it. Enable custom errors as suggested above, and RDP into the server and try to open the site from a browser on the server. If you can't log in to the server, try setting it to `mode="Off"` and browse again.

Comment: Another nice trick is to enable [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fwh2ss9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Add `<healthMonitoring enabled="true"/>` to your web.config, then look for ASP.NET **warning** messages in the "Application" event log on the server.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, you are right! Thank you for the patience! It does not give me any error when i remotely login to the server, open the solution and debug it, i can connect to the database. The page i am trying is login page and when the dataset is null, show the user does not exist , if not open the home page. On the live website, it does say "User does not exist". That made me think that the DLL that i was calling to get a Dataset is messed up or something. But as you said, it might not be the case. I will go into this deeply and find out.